# Перевод из varchar в date

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть поле,где дата храниться в varchar ,нужно перевести date.
Создал новое поле и прописал

```
UPDATE reestrs
SET
  new_date = concat(
  substring_index(srok_deust, '.', -1), '-',
  substring_index(substring_index(srok_deust, '.', 2), '.', -1), '-',
  substring_index(srok_deust, '.', 1));
```

дата везде 01.01.0001.
Что интересно,что запрос  ниже все правильно делает

```
SELECT srok_deust
     , concat(substring_index(srok_deust, '.', -1), '-',
       substring_index(substring_index(srok_deust, '.', 2), '.', -1), '-',
       substring_index(srok_deust, '.', 1)) AS new_date
FROM
  reestrs;
```

Подскажите,пожалуйста,где проблема?

Comment: содержимое srok_deust покажите. пожалуйста. из чего конвертируете?

Comment: Но вообще-то в MySQL функция для этого есть: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: @cyadvert, вот такого вида строка 10.06.2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно воспользоваться функцией `STR_TO_DATE()`
Вот доки: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

В принципе все просто: даете строку и указываете, что это дата в таком-то формате. И `MySQL` сама прочитает ее.

Т.е. если в Вашем примере 10.06.2017 это шестое октября, то вот так:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10.06.2017', '%m.%d.%Y');
```

если же это десятое июня, то вот так:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('10.06.2017', '%d.%m.%Y');
```

Comment: а не подскажите,как сразу по всему столбцу пройти?А это делать в поле varchar ,а потом этому полю менять тип на date?

Comment: `UPDATE reestrs SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(srok_deust, '%d.%m.%Y');` Еще раз - внимательней с тем, где месяц, а где день.